# Optimum time to perform an operation: within, or after loop

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I am reading a file to parse later on. The file is not likely to exceed an MB in size, so this is perhaps not a crucial question for me at this stage. But for best practise reasons, I'd like to know when is the optimum time to perform an operation.

Example:

Using a method I've pasted from http://www.dzone.com/snippets/java-read-file-string, I am reading a buffer into a string. I would now like to remove all whitespace. My method is currently this:

```
private String listRaw;

public boolean readList(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1024);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
        buf = new char[1024];
    }
    reader.close();
    listRaw = fileData.toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
    return true;
}
```

So, I remove all whitespace from the string at the time I store it - in it's entirety - to a class variable.

To me, this means less processing but more memory usage. Would I be better off applying the `replaceAll()` operation on the `readData` variable as I append it to `fileData` for best practise reasons? Using more processing but avoiding passing superfluous whitespace around.

I imagine this has little impact for a small file like the one I am working on, but what if it's a 200MB log file?

Is it entirely case-dependant, or is there a consensus I'd do better to follow?

---

Thanks for the input everybody. I'm sure you've helped to aim my mindset in the right direction for writing Java.

I've updated my code to take into consideration the points raised. Including the suggestion by Don Roby that at some point, I may want to keep spaces. Hopefully things read better now!

```
private String listRaw;

public boolean readList(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {
    StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder(51200);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[51200];
    boolean spaced = false;
    while(reader.read(buf) != -1){
        for(int i=0;i<buf.length;i++) {
            char c = buf[i];
            if (c != '\t' && c != '\r' && c != '\n') {
                if (c == ' ') {
                    if (spaced) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    spaced = true;
                } else {
                    spaced = false;
                }

                fileData.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    listRaw = fileData.toString().trim();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Measure it and find out! That way you know which is actually faster, not what someone thinks should be faster.

Comment: Good point! As a Java newbie - and currently without any dedicated java textbooks - I'm conscious of starting with bad habits. Although I'm sure I'll have plenty by the time the day is out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd better create and apply the regexp replacement only once, at the end. But you would gain much more by

- initializing the StringBuilder with a reasonable size
- avoiding the creation of a String inside the loop, and append the read characters directly to the StringBuilder
- avoiding the instantiation of a new char buffer, for nothing, at each iteration.

To avoid an unnecessary long temporary String creation, you could read char by char, and only append the char to the StringBuilder if it's [not a whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29). In the end, the StringBuilder would contain only the good characters, and you wouldn't need any `replaceAll()` call.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look over this again now. I've done a quick Google for stringbuilder capacity and am now wading through trash. Ball park, is it perfectly ok to load several kilobytes into a buffer?

Comment: Why wouldn't it, if your memory allows it? A StringBuilder is just a wrapper over a char array.

Answer (score 3):

THere are actually several very significant inefficiencies in this code, and you'd have to fix them before worrying about the relatively less important issue you've raised.

First, don't create a new `buf` object on each iteration of the loop -- use the same one! There's no problem with doing so -- the new data overwrites the old, and you save on object allocation (which is one of the more expensive operations you can do.)

Second, similarly, don't create a `String` to call `append()` -- use the form of `append` that takes a `char` array and an offset (0, in this case) and length (`numRead`, in this case.) Again, you create one less object per loop iteration.

Finally, to come to the question you actually asked: doing it in the loop would create a String object per iteration, but with the tuning we've just done, you're creating *zero* objects per iterataion -- so removing the whitespace at the end of the loop is the clear winner!

Comment: Thank you very much for the .append() tip. Just getting used to having methods overwritten by methods of the same name with different args, all a bit alien to me. Can see I have a long way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending somewhat on the parse you're going to do, you may well be better off *not* removing the spaces in a separate step at all, and just ignore them during the parse.

It's also reasonably rare to want to remove *all* whitespace.  Are you sure you don't want to just replace multiple spaces with single spaces?

Comment: Yes, I think so. My file to parse is essentially a multi dimensional array separating dimensions with brackets and key value pairs with an equals sign. There are no string sentences, only names and numerical values.